# RxSwift .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete() not being part of core/utility library

Tags: ios, mvvm, reactive-programming, rx-swift

Trying to figure out how to make an app with RxSwift and exploring multiple open source projects (namely [CleanArchitectureRxSwift](https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift) and [SwiftHub](https://github.com/khoren93/SwiftHub)) I often find usage of

```
extension ObservableType {

    func asDriverOnErrorJustComplete() -> Driver<E> {
        return asDriver { error in
            return Driver.empty()
        }
    }

}
```

Given that this method is useful in many situation and literally copied in mentioned projects I wonder why is it not a part of some utility library (like for example [RxSwiftExt](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt)) or even RxSwift itself.

I find it really suspicious that given how many Rx pods there are in [SwiftHub Podfile](https://github.com/khoren93/SwiftHub/blob/master/Podfile#L18) none of them actually contain this function.

My question is that are there any real reasons behind that? Does `asDriverOnErrorJustComplete` somehow violates come Rx contracts or considered bad practice etc?

Am I biased in sense that those two projects are most likely copied architecture from each other and are not representative? If so, are there any good open source projects that demonstrate RxSwift+MVVM and maybe avoid `asDriverOnErrorJustComplete` or approach problems solved by `asDriverOnErrorJustComplete` differently?

Comment: Nice question with thumb up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't call the method bad practice *per se* but it allows for an error that will get silently ignored which I don't particularly like. Using such a construct is rather pernicious in that your chain will silently fail without any notice at all. It could be a problem if your QA department (you with a different hat on?) doesn't notice the fact that the label isn't updating anymore.

I'm also not a big fan of the particular GitHub repos you call out because they add a lot of IMHO unnecessary boilerplate. I prefer code that is more direct.

In my sample app [RxEarthquake](https://github.com/danielt1263/RxEarthquake), I use the following:

```
public func asDriverLogError(_ file: StaticString = #file, _ line: UInt = #line) -> SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, E> {
    return asDriver(onErrorRecover: { print("Error:", $0, " in file:", file, " atLine:", line); return .empty() })
}
```

So at least a record of the error is made in debug.

I also think the following is an excellent alternative:

```
public func asDriverOrAbort(_ file: StaticString = #file, _ line: UInt = #line) -> SharedSequence<DriverSharingStrategy, E> {
    return asDriver(onErrorRecover: { fatalError("Error: \($0) in file: \(file) atLine: \(line)") })
}
```

By using such a method, you are making it clear to the reader that you are absolutely sure that the chain won't produce an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a thorough answer! I'm also exploring mentioned project and find it very useful! From what I read is it safe to say that different developers could prefer different ways of handling errors "caught" by Driver and there is no consensus on how such errors should (and wether at all) be handled thus leading us to opinionated issue and that's the reason why such methods (neither `asDriverOnErrorJustComplete` nor `asDriverLogError`) are _not_ included in popular Rx libraries?

Comment: I think that's fair to say. The whole point of a Driver is that no error will be emitted and so how to handle an error if it _is_ emitted isn't really defined. Also, `Driver` itself is a relatively new addition to the library and I'm not sure if best practices have been settled on yet.

Answer (score 2):

I think `asDriverOnErrorJustComplete` is not included in the standard library, because with any type of observable except `void`, the application will be crashed when receiving an error.

When I started writing SwiftHub, I couldn’t understand why the application crashes when I got an error from the server :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Great job with SwiftHub BTW!